# How do I fix Eclipse project where maven dependencies are listed right under project but also under 'Maven Dependencies' folder?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies

I have this weird problem. It was working fine, but lately after some developers joined the project, all of a sudden Maven dependencies are listed both under Maven Dependencies folder as well as under the project. Please see pic. I've highlighted a sample dependency that's listed twice.

[image]

So far, it seems like the project compiles fine, etc etc. But it just annoys me to see that. Any ideas how to fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might happen when people insert external dependencies manually in the build path as follows:

> Select Project > Right Click > Properties > Java Build Path > Add External JARs...

You can get rid of unwanted external libraries by removing them from the **top level** list (**don't remove** `JRE System Library` and `Maven Dependencies`). As these libraries are managed by Maven you don't need to include them into the project manually.

And the reason why you're seeing configuration changes of other developers is that when `Eclipse .settings`, `.classpath` and `.project` files are checked into the Repository. (Remove these entries from the repository if you have authorization to do so and you'll have a clean repository.)